# Why can optim() be used recursively in R

Tags: r, optimization, recursion

I am hoping someone can clear something up for me please. I am using optim to optimise a set of parameters to fit a model to a timeseries. The code works fine and optimises fine.

However, I recently read on the [optim help](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html) page that you can use optim() recursively. So I implemented this and it improves the fit over multiple recursions.

My question is this: If optim is already optimising over the parameter space and spitting out an optimal answer for that starting condition, why is the fit improved by using it recursively, repeatedly? This seems unintuitive.

Many thanks!

Comment: I do not know, but maybe it uses the estimates from the first solution as starting values for the next solution.  That sometimes improves model fit by avoiding local maxima.  However, I do not know that this is the case in your situation and perhaps I completely misunderstand the question.

Comment: Hi - that is exactly what it does (as advised on the help page to use optim() recursively). I guess I am struggling to understand *why* this works - surely the first solution should be optimal already? Avoiding local maxima might be the reason. I'll keep working on it... thanks!

Comment: The first solution is not always the global maxima.  Sometimes a search algorithm gets trapped in a local maxima.  If search algorithms were perfect I suppose they always would provide the global maxima the first time.  If you want to know why your particular algorithm sometimes fails initially, you will need to tell us which algorithm you are using, and you would probably be better off posting on Cross Validated.  I suppose another reason an algorithm might fail initially is if there simply were not enough iterations available to find the global maxima the first time.